# Two sided encryption php

Tags: php, mcrypt

I'm looking for a simple two sided encryption for URL paths hiding. I've tried using mcrypt but I keep getting random encrypted string for the same word. I don't want to use anything that requires DB to save the encryptions.
Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: If you're getting a "random encrypted string" well, then .. You're doing it wrong. (Post the relevant code as a *minimal* test-case: pay attention to the encryption algorithm/mode and those pesky details like IV.)

Comment: I'm not near my computer at the moment. But I will within an hour..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
base64_encode
base64_decode
or
urlencode
urldecode
```